# Is there any way to clear the .Net string intern pool?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, profiling

I have an application that, over time, adds more and more strings into the string intern pool. The interned strings are added by various libraries (not necessarily mine), so I can't control the amount of string being added. The application's private bytes seem to grow at about 5 GB per 24 hours. Memory profiling shown that the strings being held are held by the intern pool (no other reference to them).

Is there a way to periodically empty the intern pool every X hours?

I would like to emphasize that the memory growth occurs because of the interned string pool growth. To verify this I have written the following simple program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            string str = i.ToString().PadLeft(1000);
            string.Intern(str);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("all strings interned");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

That quickly grows the memory to 200MB, and remains constant at that size until closed (even though the interned strings have no reference other than the interned string pool).

[image: The program's memory usage]

Comment: Unused strings should and would be garbage collected. If they are not, they are used somewhere.

Comment: From `String.Intern`'s documentation, FWIW: `the memory allocated for interned String objects is not likely to be released until the common language runtime (CLR) terminates`